# Includes a delegate in a Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We'd normally use `.includes` when we fetch a list of objects whose model is in relation with some other model. For example, if an `Author` `has_many :books`, we'd probably do something like this:

```
Author.all.includes(:books).map do |author|
    author.do_something_with_all_his_books
end
```

So here comes the question - what if I have a `Book` that `delegate :author to ...` and I'd like to do something similar to what I have above but just flipped, *something like:*

```
Book.all.includes(:author).map do |book|
    book.do_something_with_all_its_authors
end
```

where I only have a `delegate` relationship from a `Book` to its `Author`, how should I make the above happen? I could certainly do `book.author` to each `Book`, but the number of queries will explode I had a lot more books, so I'd like to prevent that problem with something like `include`.

**Problem I'm having right now:**

An error message `Association named 'author' was not found on Book` was raised.

Thanks

Comment: So you mean you have no `author_id` as Fkey in the `Book` model, am I right?

Comment: Your _edited_ error message gives the answer. I would add the `author_id` column to the `Book` model to achieve what you are trying to do. `delegate` will not work with `includes`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, if `includes` doesn't work with `delegate`, is there any other way to do the same thing without adding a foreign key?

Comment: Yes just do `Book.all.map do |book|
    book.do_something_with_all_its_authors
end`. Btw, why do you want to use `includes` there though?

Comment: It depends on what you've delegated author to - you will have to include the underlying association(s)

Comment: @ddolce what frederick said is correct. can you show those 2 models and where you are delegating ?